# jquery not update the div

Tags: jquery, time

i have a problem with jquery load function

```
jQuery(function(){
var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
    jQuery('.timeago').load(location.href+' .timeago>*');
}, 5000);
});
```

`After 5 seconds .timeago div just disappears! Why?` Where is the problem or there is another way how to do this?

P.S. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: what is this unable to get this:.timeago>*

Answer (score 0):

try `$(.yourDiv).trigger('create')` after the load